# PROLOG - Checking for correct placement

Tags: prolog, puzzle, clpfd

I have a puzzle that is a 3*3 grid with numbers 1-8 in them, with a blank spot (0) that I can move around.  This is the final state of the puzzle:

```
1 2 3 
8 0 4 
7 6 5
```

This whole "state" is represented by state(1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5), by reading horizontally.  I need a function to check to see which pieces are in the right spots.

I have:

```
h(state(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I),Z) :-
```

Now Z is going to be the number of pieces in the correct spot.

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 8
E = 0
F = 4
G = 7
H = 6
I = 5
```

Is there any easy way to give an output for Z?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems rather simple to do...

```
h(state(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I),Z) :-
    count_matching([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I], [1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5], 0, Z).

count_matching([], [], N, N).
count_matching([A|As], [B|Bs], N, M) :-
    (   A == B
    ->  T is N + 1
    ;   T is N
    ),
    count_matching(As, Bs, T, M).
```

SWI-Prolog aggregate library offers another easy way to solve your problem:

```
:- [library(aggregate)].

h(state(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I),Z) :-
    aggregate_all(count,
      (nth1(Index, [1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5], Cell),
       nth1(Index, [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I], Cell)), Z).
```

Using aggregate_all is overkill: here a simpler program using the same schema (non deterministic access to elements via nth/3):

```
h(state(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I),Z) :-
    findall(_,
      (nth1(Index, [1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5], Cell),
       nth1(Index, [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I], Cell)), L),
    length(L, Z).
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you can't store your information in lists? This is kinda how in a traditional language you use arrays instead of just a bunch of variables if you want a way to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a short way of expressing this in Prolog, but it requires [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

h(State, Z) :-
    State =.. [state | Pos],
    maplist(equal, Pos, [0,1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5], Eq),
    sum(Eq, #=, Z).

equal(X, Y, E) :-
    E #<==> (X #= Y).
```